# Pandas : want to explode data based on start and end date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i want to explode dataframe based on start and end data. It should be in an interval of 10 days or last number of days for each month. For example, my input dataframe looks like :

df

```
id,start_date,end_date,points
1,2020-01-01,2020-01-20,100
2,2020-01-11,2020-02-10,200
3,2020-04-21,2020-05-10,300
4,2020-02-21,2020-03-10,400
```

my output should look like :

```
id,start_date,end_date,points,number_of_days
1,2020-01-01,2020-01-10,100,10
1,2020-01-11,2020-01-20,100,10
2,2020-01-11,2020-01-20,200,10
2,2020-01-21,2020-01-31,200,11
2,2020-02-01,2020-02-10,200,10
3,2020-04-21,2020-04-30,300,10
3,2020-05-01,2020-05-10,300,10
4,2020-02-21,2020-02-29,400,9
4,2020-03-01,2020-03-10,400,10
```

Comment: Can you explicitly define the logic to be used to explode the database.  For example, why does your expected output contain each additional line.

Comment: I am reading records from Excel file, not any database.  It's not necessary I have to use explode function. I just need the expected output.  Expected output should contain the start and end date at an interval of 10 days or for last slot, it can contain 8,9,10,11 days depends on the month and year.

Comment: I still don't understand how you are translating your input to desired output.  What is the explicit logic for each output line?:

Comment: I didn't translated to desired output. I want the logic to translate into desired output

Comment: @BasantJain please let me know if my answer was helpful

Answer (score 3):

This can be quite tricky. First of all, I assume your data is indexed by the `id` column, if it's not, you can do it easily with:

```
df.set_index("id", inplace = True)
```

Also, make sure to use `datetime` columns:

```
df["start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_date"])
df["end_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end_date"])
```

One last thing to consider, I used [`pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) to add days to dates:

```
def add_days(date, days):
    return date + pd.DateOffset(days=days)
```

Now, let's begin. The most difficult thing in my opinion is to build a function which splits the date intervals. keep in mind this function may receives a row from the original dataframe as argument and it must return **multiple rows**. I do so returning a list:

```
def split_dates(row):

    start = row["start_date"]
    end = row["end_date"]
    points = row["points"]
    new_row = []

    curr_date = start
    while curr_date < end:

        delta_days = 10
        curr_date_aux = add_days(curr_date, delta_days)

        if curr_date_aux.day != curr_date.daysinmonth:
            delta_days = 9
            curr_date_aux = add_days(curr_date, delta_days)

        if curr_date_aux > end:
            delta_days = (end-start).days
            curr_date_aux = add_days(curr_date, delta_days)
        
        if curr_date_aux.month != curr_date.month:
            delta_days = -curr_date.day + curr_date.daysinmonth
            curr_date_aux = add_days(curr_date, delta_days) 
        
        new_row.append([curr_date, curr_date_aux, points, delta_days + 1])
        curr_date = add_days(curr_date_aux, 1)

    return new_row
```

Now you can [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) this function row-wise and, with [`pandas.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html?highlight=explode#pandas.Series.explode), you can transform each element from the lists to a new row:

```
new_dates = df.apply(split_dates, axis = 1).explode()
```

And (finally) get the desired dataframe:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_dates.tolist(),
    index = new_dates.index,
    columns = ["start_date", "end_date", "points", "number of days"])

#   start_date   end_date  points  number of days
#id                                              
#1  2020-01-01 2020-01-10     100              10
#1  2020-01-11 2020-01-20     100              10
#2  2020-01-11 2020-01-20     200              10
#2  2020-01-21 2020-01-31     200              11
#2  2020-02-01 2020-02-10     200              10
#3  2020-04-21 2020-04-30     300              10
#3  2020-05-01 2020-05-10     300              10
#4  2020-02-21 2020-02-29     400               9
#4  2020-03-01 2020-03-10     400              10
```